# Div background image position IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Please [take a look at this link](http://goo.gl/g2Qhp) in FF or CH and then in IE7 please.
The sliding banner has a background drop shadow which is not playing ball in IE7.

It's erratic in that it plays along sometime and other times not in the developer toolbar for IE.

Help be appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Try using a strict DOCtype instead of a transitional.  XHTML is on its way out, either use `4.01 strict` or an `html5` doctype.  See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html

Comment: Would you be able to post your code?  I tried to look for your CSS but you have so many sheets I didn't have the patience to look through them.  You mention drop shadow not appearing in IE7 - it's not simply a case of `box-shadow` not being supported is it?